Regular expression for first 2 items of comma delimited list of numbers
I want a regular expression to get only the first 2 numbers from a comma separated list, separated by an x.
Example: 1024,640,2048,1280,60
Desired: 1024x640

My best solution so far:
Search: (\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+)
Replace: $1x$2

The problem with my solution is that it only works if the list has 5 items always.
My first attempt was:
Search: (\d+),(\d+)
Replace: $1x$2

But that did not work, apparently because my search was "greedy". I've learned since then that one can make a search "not greedy" by adding a ? (for example .* --> .*?) but I've tried adding ? in many ways and it never works.
Thanks for any help

It seems there is agreement that I need to learn to get the entire list. I appreciate the help and both answers are good, but I give credit to @Abdelkader Mohamed who made me realize this first.

I have tried your pattern:
Search: (\d+),(\d+)
Replace: $1x$2

in regex101 website and the output is:
1024x640,2048,1280,60

then we need to remove the unmatched characters:
(\d+),(\d+)([,0-9]+)

now the unmatched characters are stored in $3, so when we replace it with $1x$2 the output will be 1024x640
Search: (\d+),(\d+)([,0-9]+)
Replace: $1x$2


you can even use (\d+),(\d+)(.*) and it will be the same, the idea is just to store the rest of the list in a variable $3, so when you don't put that variable $3 in the replace query, then the rest of the list will be removed from the output.

This is not a matter of greedy or not, but making sure that you:

only match the numbers at the start of the list. You can use ^ to assert that
match also all the other numbers, outside of the capture groups you use in the replace part, so that they are removed ((,\d+)*).

Search: ^(\d+),(\d+)(,\d+)*
Replace: $1x$2

If the list is not at the start of the input, and you still need to match those two elements, then use a look-behind assertion to require that there should not be a comma before the first number:
Search: (?<!,)(\d+),(\d+)(,\d+)*
Replace: $1x$2


Thank you @trincot for the reply. Yes, the list is at the start of the input. I tried your solution using this website https://regex101.com/ but it didn't work. It gives this for your first solution: 1024x640,2048,1280,60 -- Am I doing something wrong? It also didn't work in this site: https://regexr.com/

Ah, I see you want you mean. I updated my answer. You need to get all the rest of the list .
